# Electron packager not packaging the app, without any error

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to package the app with Electron packager for the Linux platform but the packaging is not happening. The app is not getting built at all. It was working fine when the node version was v11.15.0. Earlier I was using the older MacBook where it was working. Currently, I am using a MacBook pro M1 and my node version is v15.3.0.

Package.json-

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . myapp --overwrite --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/images/logos/logo-72x72.png --prune=true --out=release-builds"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
   "@angular/cli": "~7.0.6",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.7",
   "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
   "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
   "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
   "@types/node": "^8.10.43",
   "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
   "electron": "^15.3.0",
   "electron-packager": "^15.4.0",
   "typescript": "~3.1.6"
}
```

This is the command I am using -

```
electron-packager . myapp --asar --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=src/assets/images/logos/logo-72x72.png --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

My terminal log after running this command -

```
> Packaging app for platform linux x64 using electron v15.3.0
```

and then the process is terminated.

Earlier it was (When it was working) -

```
> Packaging app for platform linux x64 using electron v15.3.0
> Wrote new app to release-builds/myapp-linux-x64
```

Wine is also installed. If I remove **"--asar"** from the command then it is getting packaged but the size of the app is going to be 650 MB which I don't want, but with **"--asar"** the process is not moving forward. Earlier it was only 280 MB. Any error is also not occurring. Not sure why it is behaving this way. Can someone help me?

Comment: No error message at all? Please share your configuration and so on, so we can help you more easier

Comment: @Batajus, I have added the package.json to the question. Node version is v15.3.0 and Yes, there are no errors at all.